Simple form with many collection inputs stalls after render, Rails
I've got a simple_form that has 22 inputs with collections like:
collection: 0..1000

and another 22 inputs with collections like:
collection: 0..10000

So that's a form with 242000 in collections, which causes the form to stall after rendering for maybe 7 seconds on local server.
I thought the collections were nice, but will not use them unless there's a quicker solution?

If your collections are truly numeric I would suggest a range or a number field (both of which are supported by simple_form) rather than a select. If your collections are actually collections of objects you are probably going to want to implement some kind of type to search functionality.

✓I liked collection because it forced user to select appropriate numbers, but loaded slow. Now it's fast with number fields. Range would have been nice if it showed the exact number value along with the slider.

That's a pretty easy addition to range. It's even included in the Docs provided by Mozilla.

"I liked collection because it forced user to select appropriate numbers". That's an inherently unsafe way to think about it. Clients can send whatever they want to your server. Your form provides no guarentees about the correctness of the data in any way. You should instead just focus on making the entire process as easy and smooth as possible because no one likes filling out forms. Having a select with more than maybe 10 options (unless its countries) is borderline unusable.

Noted. I appreciate that, thank you, validations and strong params, and agreed, removing the 242 000 options flows better lol

It's hard to say how many elements are too many but you'll start to run into memory issues on simpler mobile devices already at a few thousand DOM nodes.
